# How to add title in Navigation drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, navigation-drawer

[UPDATE]

I solve the problem by adding addHeaderView :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup mTop = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview_menu, mDrawerList, false);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(mTop, null, false);
```

================================

My question is so simple !

I would like to how to add a title in a navigation drawer ?

I already created my navigation drawer with listview (icon+text) for each item.

Thanks a lot,

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to add several titles?

Comment: Do you have a more complete code sample?

Comment: i also want to add this title. can you describe how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `TextView` above a `ListView`, and wrap it inside a vertical `LinearLayout` . Give to your ListView `android:layout_weight="1"`  and `android:layout_height="0dip"`

Comment: That will work if the header is to be fixed at the top. The screenshot shows headers as part of the `ListView` itself (see "Title 2" row). Your solution may be what the OP is seeking, though.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood him. Only now I realized he wants

Comment: ooohhh..... never give 0dip tu height of a listview.. try it and see in DDMS how long does the method "onMeasure" takes to be executed..

Answer (score 11):

You would do that the same way as you would add headings in any other `ListView`, by teaching your `ListAdapter` to return heading rows as well as detail rows. At the low level, this involves overriding methods like `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in your `ListAdapter`, plus having `getView()` know the difference between the row types. Or, use an existing high-level implementation like https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders or http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/ or any of the others found when searching for `android listview headers`.

Comment: related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late but I think I have a simpler solution. In your Activity's layout, instead of adding a listView inside the DrawerLayout, you can add for example a LinearLayout, and you can easily add separators and rows. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Separator 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Separator 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the Activity, you can add the listeners to the buttons.

Hope that helps!