# how can I add an image to the bottom of a Drawer view?

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

So i'm wanting to be able to place an logo image at the bottom of my drawer view separate from the list. I've seen people do similar things with other list view and things like that, but whenever I try implementing that i get a lot of java errors. any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

here's my layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#f4f8f9" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've seen in a few places to change the frame layout to a relative layout, but every time i do that i get an error.

here's my java code:

```
public class someActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] mDrawerItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ShelfArrayAdapter(this, mDrawerItems)); 
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setSubtitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setSubtitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mDrawerItems[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        // this changes fragments. 
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a RelativeLayout inside your FrameLayout (child). Then you can put your logo at the bottom ! Hope that works!

**Edit**

Sorry, I thought it would be that simple, but I got it working !

Try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ratafeia"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="240dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rata" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the Java code:
Add at the global variables:

```
RelativeLayout ratafeia;
```

Before `mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`:

```
ratafeia = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ratafeia);
```

Replace: `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);` with `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(ratafeia);`

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList)
with mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(ratafeia);
```

Bottom line, replace every mDrawerList with your relativeLayout !

I've tested and it is working here !

Comment: I appreciate the quick response... I tried that, but i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams.. I think there must be something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you an idea, Try the below logic (Use a wrapper for ListView) , it should work

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#f4f8f9" />

<ImageView 
// Load your image here
with align parent bottom
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I apreceate the quick response. I tried implementing this... and I got this error Jva.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start activity ... java.lang.classcastexception : andrid.widget.relitiveLayut$LayoutPrams cannot be cast to android.suport.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$layoutPrams.... which I'm pretty sure is the same error I got last time I tried this... is there something I need to change in my Java code?

Comment: See my answer below. The error is probably because in the drawer layout the Left (widget) is your RelativeLayout and some where in your code (drawer.close()/ drawer.open()) I suspect, you are still referring your ListView instead of the newly added RelativeLayout. Change that and the error should vanish (fingers crossed).

Comment: Remove your listview gravity `android:layout_gravity="start"` and post your logcat

Answer (score -1):

See the layout I created myself to achieve a similar thing, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621673/adding-a-linear-layout-to-navigation-drawer-ends-up-crashing-with-a-classcastex).

Also, at the time of closing the drawer call drawer.close(Gravity.START), don't pass listView object here, pass the relative layout instead.