# Contents not showing up in DrawerLayout after adding a progress bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-progressbar, drawerlayout

I am new to android so I am trying to make a simple application. Everything is fine until I try to add a progress bar.

(Sorry for showing the images with a hyperlink as I don't have enough reputation to post images)

How it looks like:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOdY.png)

What I wanted to have is something like:
[draft layout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPnkY.png)

main_activity before adding a progress bar:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/credit_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/credit" >
</TextView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

(The closing tag for DrawerLayout is at the end but I don't know why it is not showing up if I start a new line with it)

Then I want to add a progress bar under the textView which acts as a label. After I insert a ProgressBar element in main_activity.xml, a progress bar appeared in the middle of the screen but that's not what I exactly wanted.

Afterwards I tried to use a LinearLayout element to wrap up the TextView and ProgressBar, trying to arrange and display them accordingly, with the xml file shown below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credit_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/credit" >
    </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/credit_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

But the progress bar is not showing up, it turns out that only the TextView label is showing up. Upon interchanging the order of the TextView and ProgressBar elements, an error will occur stating that I am casting PorgressBar to TextView, but I don't know how this happenes with the following line of code:

```
TextView credit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.credit_label);
```

I read another topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621673/adding-a-linear-layout-to-navigation-drawer-ends-up-crashing-with-a-classcastex?rq=1)) in stackoverflow, stating that there can only be 3 elements in the drawerlayout, I tried to use the LinearLayout to wrap up all stuffs except the left_drawer list, so I tried the following version:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credit_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/credit" >
    </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/credit_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

This time it didn't stop unop starting the application, but the FrameLayout consists of the fragment displaying the expandable list will shows nothing (white blank in that place). I am very frustrated and I don't know what the problems are, hence finally came here and hope to get some help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: when r u trying to hide progres bar?

Comment: actually I don't want to hide it, instead I want to keep showing the progress bar, and update it whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: yes but ur progress bar is match parent

Comment: what is the problem of match parent for progress bar ?

Comment: SOLVED: I made all of them display correctly through changing LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, following with adjusting the margin of each elements. But I still don't know why LinearLayout didn't work.